# "Search for them" vs "Search them" in relation to online searches

Tags: grammaticality, expressions

This might be the wrong place - if so, I can delete.

I'm looking for correct language guidance regarding a line on a lead generation web application where we allow a user to search for more information on the selected lead (a person) using various websites (Google, LinkedIn, Twitter, etc.), and using the site's icons as a clickable button.

Currently, it reads "**Search for them on: (google)(Facebook)**"
I have a request to change it to "**Search them on: (google)(Facebook)**"

I believe that the original label is correct and that the requested change doesn't actually have the same meaning, but I'm getting some pushback on my assertion.

Am I correct in my statement that "Search for them on Google" is the appropriate sentence, and that "Search them on Google" has a wholly different meaning?

Comment: Hello, jslowik. How do dictionaries say 'search' and 'search for' are generally used? Have you reason that there are different conventions in computerese (if so, ELU is _not_ the best place to ask about these).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks for the question! To be clear, I'm interested in the correct use rather than what might be understood by a technical team. This sentence will be presented to users. I just wasn't super sure how to set up the question w/o the context. The definition of search tends to be similar to "to look through, look at or examine, explore or examine". My belief is that if you remove the preposition, the meaning of the sentence changes. I have no actual power with this decision, so my question is really more academic.

Comment: I would say *Search **Firstname Lastname** on:* [Google] [Facebook], where *Firstname Lastname* actually represents a query term. I assume you're passing those parameters for the search? In this case, *for* would not be used.

Comment: @TinfoilHat: Many people would use _for_ in that case...

Comment: The direct object of [search](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/search) is generally the thing you are searching within; you "search *container* for *sought-thing*" ([see also Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/search)). I think there may be an alternative construction "search *sought-thing*", as Tinfoil Hat says, but if so, it is a newer usage associated with search engines, and hence not in the dictionaries I checked.

Comment: Why not just “search on”?

Comment: We hit this conundrum is due to design decisions and space constraints. One reason we aren't more verbose about what's being searched is we may have additional information that can be plugged into the query parameters (like location as an example) depending on platform, so we kept it to a generic "them" (being the lead in question.

I think the "Search fname lname" thing can work because at that point what you're doing is running a search string on Google, but our context seems to be the lead (which, again, is a person).

Comment: @StuartF: From the *OED*: **4. b. (c)** *transitive.* With the subject of the search, esp. a search term, as object. ..... Examples given: **1985** *The topic ‘clinical ladder’ demonstrates this advantage. In Nursing & Allied Health..you can search the term directly.* **2019** *Uploaded a bunch of new gifs to instagram. search ‘cash cash’ to check em all out!!*

Comment: Also, when you're searching for the lead, you're actually searching a name that matches the lead's, and any number of the results might not be that lead, just someone with the same name. Better to make that clear somehow (like emphasizing a query-centric framework rather than person-centric one).

Comment: @TinfoilHat I think you're right that there's a larger language problem at play here, which might be from a lack of understanding of exactly what's going on with these buttons on our design side. I'll definitely attempt to push for some overall clarity based on your suggestions.

Comment: @Tinfoil Hat The OED examples licensing "search DO" = "search for / search out / seek DO" and "search '_quote_' " = "look for '_quote_' " are vital here. May Andy Bonner add them to his answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Search," by itself, is a transitive verb. "Search them," without context, means "investigate them closely." "Search for" is the most common construction to indicate a search term.

Tinfoil Hat gives some examples of "search [query]," in which "search" is used transitively, so this usage is common enough that your point would be understood. However, even this colloquial construction breaks down when you add the prepositional phrase indicating the search platform, "search them on Google."

All of the following would be idiomatically appropriate:

- Search for them on ___
- Look them up on ___
- Search ___ for them

... and, of course, in the most prominent example of "verbing nouns"... "Google them."